# Mongoose Find Method Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

EDIT: Resolved. It was just missing a bracket at the end of the if statement.

Thank you for your time!

The line at which I used Hotel.find doesn't appear to be executed, so the code below it doesn't work at all. I didn't get any errors or warnings. It just doesn't do anything. I don't understand what I did wrong.

```
function getPlaces() {

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/gtdb");
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "Connection error:"));
db.once("open", function(callback) {

//Define the hotel schema.
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var hotelSchema = new Schema({
  "PlaceName" : String,
  "PlaceType" : String,
  "PlaceAddress" : String,
  "Telephone" : String,
  "PlaceCity" : String,
  "ZipCode" : Number,
  "State" : String,
  "Country" : String,
  "EstimatedPrice" : Number,
  "PhotoUrl" : String,
  "OtherDetails" : String
 }); 

var Hotel = mongoose.model("Hotel", hotelSchema);

if (searchtype == "Hotel") {
  console.log("Request received for hotel data.");

  Hotel.find(function(err, hotels) { //This is the line it won't execute.
  var i;
    console.log(hotels);
    console.log("Find test");

  for (i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
     dataarray[i] = hotels[i];
  }
 });

} else if (searchtype == "Event") {
    Event.find(function(err, events) {
 });
}

    mongoose.disconnect();

 }); //End of db.once function.
} //End of the getPlaces function.
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't think that there is a `find` function which only takes one parameter? If you want to 'search' all items, you would use `{}` as parameter for the query.

Comment: And, typically, you would keep your mongodb connection open for the lifetime of your application and not open/close it for each query. The schema should be defined once globally as well.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clean up the indenting? It's really hard to read.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Ok, does it look better now?

Comment: what is dataarray[i] = hotels[i];?

Comment: @qqilihq - you can pass only a callback, as you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/78fa27ff83a9783ba2c2f67b637b3e97adc82f85/lib/model.js#L1116). @Nicholas - are you sure you don't get the `"Find test"` console log? And most importantly - the `"Request received for hotel data."` msg? I don't see where `searchtype` is set!

Comment: @NicholasBrown Not really, no. :) Look at the end of your code.

Comment: @AndreyPopov I get the 'Request received for hotel data.' message, but not 'Find test'. searchtype is declared in the program. This is only a fraction of the code you're seeing. dataarray is another array which I pass to response.send.

Comment: Problem solved. It was a missing bracket at the end of the if statement. Thanks. :)

Comment: @NicholasBrown One of the many reasons that proper indenting is so important! :)